# Can 1 ASB-queue forward to-many queues?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I was trying to forward a message to one queue, that worked perfectly. However, is it possible to forward the message to another queue at the same time? I was using Service Bus Explorer since my experience with ASB is limited. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. A queue could forward messages to a topic and the topic might have a fan-out set-up that would distribute to subscriptions (also queues in a way), or have subscriptions with auto-forwarding to other queues.